# Adapt a formula to ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im very new to Google Sheets formulas.
Im trying to convert this formula:

```
=INDEX(PRX_ARM,MATCH(ELECTRICITE!E97,OFFSET(PRX_ARM_C1,0,MATCH(ELECTRICITE!G97,PRX_ARM_L1 
,1)-1),1), MATCH(ELECTRICITE!G97&"1",PRX_ARM_L1,1))+ 
ELECTRICITE!H97*INDEX(PRX_REL,2,2)+ 
ELECTRICITE!I97*INDEX(PRX_REL,3,2)+
ELECTRICITE!J97*INDEX(PRX_BP_VOY,2,2)+ 
ELECTRICITE!K97*INDEX(PRX_BP_VOY,3,2)+
ELECTRICITE!L97*INDEX(PRX_BP_VOY,4,2)+
ELECTRICITE!M97*INDEX(PRX_BP_VOY,5,2)
```

So naturally, i converted every single cell reference to the range ArrayFormula must be applied to :

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(PRX_ARM,MATCH(ELECTRICITE!E90:E5030,OFFSET(PRX_ARM_C1,0,MATCH(ELECTRICITE!G90:G5030,PRX_ARM_L1,1)-1),1),
MATCH(ELECTRICITE!G90&"1",PRX_ARM_L1,1))+
ELECTRICITE!H90:H5030*INDEX(PRX_REL,2,2)+
ELECTRICITE!I90:I5030*INDEX(PRX_REL,3,2)+
ELECTRICITE!J90:J5030*INDEX(PRX_BP_VOY,2,2)+
ELECTRICITE!K90:K5030*INDEX(PRX_BP_VOY,3,2)+
ELECTRICITE!L90:L5030*INDEX(PRX_BP_VOY,4,2)+
ELECTRICITE!M90:M5030*INDEX(PRX_BP_VOY,5,2))
```

But it does not work.
Do you know what im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yu can't use index with arrayformula, use instead vlookup

Comment: Allright, that was simple. Thank you!